# How to select an image from resources via a string?

Tags: vb.net, embedded-resource

I'm coding a pokedex type deal as practice for my class.
Basically, I have a class titled "pokemon". One of the properties of the class is "ImgName" Which I want to use to display an image from the resources with the same name.

VB doesn't allow me to call the ImgName as a string and then use 'My.Resources.ImgName'

How can i do this, or what are some alternative options to it? I want it to be determined by a property in the pokemon object, and i don't want to have to hard code in an if-elseif statement for every single pokemon.

Answer (score 0):

One way is you can have a resource file added to your project. Then drop the resource into it. You will be able to address it like this:

```
My.Resources.Resource1.ImgName
```

`Resource1` is your resource file name, and `ImgName` is the resource name here. But you need to do hard code for every call. However, you get full intellisense support with type checking.

If you don't want hard code, here is a stripped down version of my production code:

```
Imports System.Reflection
Imports System.Xml.Linq

Public Class EmbeddedResourceManager
  Private Class EmbeddedResourceManagerCore
    Private Shared _executingAssembly As Assembly
    Private Shared _resourcePrefix As String

    Shared Sub New()
      _executingAssembly = Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly
      _resourcePrefix = _executingAssembly.GetName.Name & "."
    End Sub

    Public Shared Function GetStream(resourceRelName As String) As IO.Stream
      Return _executingAssembly.GetManifestResourceStream(_resourcePrefix & resourceRelName)
    End Function
  End Class

  Public Shared Function GetImage(ByVal resourceName As String) As Bitmap
    Return New Bitmap(EmbeddedResourceManagerCore.GetStream(resourceName))
  End Function
End Class
```

So whenever you need, just call `EmbeddedResourceManager.GetImage` and pass the resource name, as it appears in your project (your image file needs to be attached to a project). You need to have `Build Action` for an image in question to be set to `Embedded Resource`.

This piles up all your resource into an executable, which has both benefits and drawbacks, depending on the situation. Still, it should work for your needs, since I am assuming number of different pokemons is limited and does not change throughout the game (i.e. downloaded from a 3rd party server in real time etc.).

Comment: When I attempt to use your code, I get an error saying that the Type 'bitmap' is not defined, is this something you have defined in your code, or am i missing something?

Comment: @user2259724: [Bitmap](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-ca/library/system.drawing.bitmap.aspx) is a standard .NET class. It needs `System.Drawing` namespace, but you should have that added automatically when you created a WinForms project.

Comment: Ah, I started the project as a console application. So that explains it, I imported it and it worked, thanks!

Comment: @user2259724: No problem, glad you were able to solve it. Please don't forget to accept this answer.

Answer (score 0):

BackgroundImage = My.Resources.ResourceManager.GetObject(aString)

10 time easier than previous answer imho